# QGIS Tile Index from raster content not extent?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

Is there a way to create a tile index from the raster content and not the extent?

Here shows the default QGIS create tile index result :

[image]

I would like the polygon to follow the outline of the skewed raster, if possible.

Comment: Try this https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/imagefootprint_plugin/ and tell if it is good.

Answer (score 1):

the [Image Footprint Plug-In suggested above](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/imagefootprint_plugin/) works a treat, it is now part of the [IBAMA processing plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ibamaprocessing/).